# How to tell capslock from tab and shift at blind typing?

Tags: emacs, keyboard

I swapped <kbd>ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>caps lock</kbd>.
Since caps lock is in between tab and shift, it is hard to tell them apart without looking.
Mis-type often happens.
Is there a good solution for this?
I am using laptop.

Comment: I usually burn a mark on the Capslock key.

Comment: You seems already know how to remap keys. So I think the answer is just 'remap it'. Or change your keyboard. There is so many keyboard in the world. US, Chinese,etc...

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this sound more like a Programmers question than a StackOverflow question?

"Getting used to it" will obviously depend on your hand size and practice, basically. Eventually your mind will just train itself with muscle memory.

Start with your left hand on home row (index on f, pinky on a) then move your hand slightly to the left naturally. Arch your hand slightly upwards and use your ring finger to hit tab, and your pinky to hit shift.

Anyways if your hand size is similar to mine, which is somewhere between a small~medium sized lab glove - you'll find the distance between the tip of your ring and pinky finger is enough to not hit caps lock in the middle if you arch your pinky a bit, which happens naturally.

Obviously don't try to move UP the keyboard with your pinky, and don't try to move DOWN the keyboard with your ring when trying to hit shift and tab respectively.

Alternatively you could almost always use right-shift :), or pull out your caps lock keycap entirely.

Reference: TyprX contest winner?

Answer (score 0):

I think depends a lot on the type of keyboard that you have. You said you're using a laptop, which obviously has the same keyboard all of the time, so adding a bump (via a burn or gluing a little half-sphere of plastic) will likely do the trick, but I'm not usually one to mark up an expensive device like that.

For me, I use an external keyboard via my desktop (and use synergy or ssh) and my Caps Lock key has an indentation (hard to describe, so I'll post an image below) so I use that to determine if my pinky finger is on the Caps Lock key or one of the other ones.

[image]

Like I said, this will depend heavily on your particular keyboard. Some of the more expensive external keyboards will allow you to replace the keys easily, so you could order one that's got the little raised bump on it.